# ASP.NET Core websocket server - connection killed when trying to send data to client

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET Core web server that communicates with clients over websockets. I've found that my server can connect to and receive data consistently from clients without problem, but cannot send data back to clients.

I'm testing the server against a websocket client I developed in Python which allows me to step through the code, and what seems to happen is that after my server sends data, the streamreader used by the websocket on Python's end encounters an EOF and closes, causing the websocket itself to close with error code 1006. I know that the client has no issues since it works against another version of this server based on the .NET Framework (which I'm migrating from).

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server` v0.1.0. Included below is my `project.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "<<Company>>.Communications.<<Product>>Usb": "0.4.7",
    "<<Company>>.<<Product>>Web.Core": {
      "target": "project"
    },
    "<<Company>>.<<Product>>WebComponentPackage": "0.4.4",
    "Common.Logging": "3.4.0-Beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server": "0.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Composition": "1.0.30",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "System.Runtime.Loader": "4.0.0",
    "Thrower": "3.0.4"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

In `Startup.cs`, I define my websocket middleware:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...

    var websocketManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<WebSocketManager>();

    app.UseWebSockets();
    app.Use(websocketManager.Acceptor);
}
```

My `WebSocketManager` class handles websocket requests:

```
public async Task Acceptor(HttpContext context, Func<Task> tasks)
{
    if (!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        return;
    }

    IWebSocketBehaviour wsBehaviour;
    var socket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
    Debug.Assert(socket.State == WebSocketState.Open);

    if (!this.TryGetWebSocketBehaviour(context, socket, out wsBehaviour))
    {
        socket.Dispose();
        return;
    }

    this.websocketBehaviours.Add(wsBehaviour);
    await wsBehaviour.Run();
    this.websocketBehaviours.Remove(wsBehaviour);
}
```

My abstract `WebSocketBehaviour` class defines `Run` as follows:

```
public async Task Run()
{
    try
    {
        var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[BufferSize]);

        this.OnOpen();
        while (this.socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult receivedMessage;

            try
            {
                receivedMessage = await this.socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, Token);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10);
                continue;
            }

            if (receivedMessage.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            {
                var data = buffer.Array.TakeWhile(x => x != 0).ToArray();
                var request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
                this.OnMessage(request);
            }
        }

        if (this.socket.CloseStatus.HasValue && (this.socket.CloseStatus.Value != WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure))
        {
            this.OnError(this.socket.CloseStatus.Value, this.socket.CloseStatusDescription);
        }

        await this.socket.CloseAsync(this.socket.CloseStatus ?? WebSocketCloseStatus.Empty,
            this.socket.CloseStatusDescription, Token);
        this.OnClose();
    }
    finally
    {
        this.socket.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And finally `Send` is defined as below:

```
protected async Task Send(string response)
{
    Raise.InvalidOperationException.If(this.socket.State != WebSocketState.Open);
    var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
    await this.socket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, Token);
}
```

In one scenario, I use my websocket client to send a request for information that should prompt a response from the server. I observe the following sequence of behaviours:

1. The client establishes a websocket connection with the server.
2. The client sends a JSON request of the form `{"op":"get", "path":"..."}`. I see the following logs on the client-side:

   ```
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,805 [DEBUG   ] asyncio - Using selector: SelectSelector
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,806 [DEBUG   ] Rx - CurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(state=None)
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,807 [DEBUG   ] Rx - CurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(state=None)
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,807 [DEBUG   ] Rx - CurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(state=None)
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,807 [DEBUG   ] Rx - CurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(state=None)
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,808 [DEBUG   ] Rx - CurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(state=None)
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,808 [DEBUG   ] Rx - CurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(state=None)
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,808 [DEBUG   ] Rx - CurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(state=None)
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,812 [INFO    ] <<Product>>.comms - Establishing connection to <<Product>> Web Service @ 127.0.0.1:5000
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,815 [DEBUG   ] asyncio - connect <socket.socket fd=860, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6> to ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,818 [DEBUG   ] asyncio - poll took 0.000 ms: 1 events
   2016-10-06 11:45:01,825 [DEBUG   ] asyncio - <socket.socket fd=860, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 60824), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 5000)> connected to 127.0.0.1:5000: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=860 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>, <websockets.client.WebSocketClientProtocol object at 0x037B5EF0>)
   2016-10-06 11:45:02,031 [DEBUG   ] asyncio - poll took 203.000 ms: 1 events
   2016-10-06 11:45:02,035 [DEBUG   ] <<Product>>.comms - Connected using websocket address: ws://127.0.0.1:5000/
   2016-10-06 11:45:02,035 [DEBUG   ] <<Product>>.component - Using read handler
   2016-10-06 11:45:02,037 [DEBUG   ] <<Product>>.comms - Sending request: {"op": "get", "path": "<<Product>>.relays[0].enabled"}
   2016-10-06 11:45:02,040 [DEBUG   ] Rx - CurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(state=None)
   2016-10-06 11:45:02,041 [DEBUG   ] <<Product>>.comms - Listening for responses
   2016-10-06 11:45:02,043 [DEBUG   ] websockets.protocol - client >> Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"op": "get", "path": "<<Product>>.relays[0].enabled"}')
   ```

   On the server side, I see:

   ```
   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/
   ```
3. The server generates a response: `{"timestamp":1475754679475,"status":"success","path":"$.relays[0].enabled","module":"<<product>>.relayController","data":[false]}`.
4. The server encodes this response as a sequence of bytes and executes `await this.socket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, Token);`
5. On the client-side, I see these additional logs:

   ```
   2016-10-06 11:56:53,155 [INFO    ] asyncio - poll took 333764.000 ms: 1 events
   2016-10-06 11:56:53,156 [DEBUG   ] asyncio - <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=820 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>> received EOF
   2016-10-06 11:56:53,157 [INFO    ] websockets.protocol - Failing the WebSocket connection: 1006
   ```

   On the server side I usually see no additional logs, but occasionally when I try this I get the following exception logs:

   ```
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4077
    ECONNRESET connection reset by peer
   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[14]
         Connection id "0HKVDQUJUEKU0" communication error
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4081
    ECANCELED operation canceled
   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<EnsureDataAvaila
   bleOrReadAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<ReadNextFrameAsy
   nc>d__37.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<ReceiveAsync>d__
   36.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
      at <<Company>>.<<Product>>Web.ServiceAdapters.WebSockets.WebSocketBehaviour.<Run>d_
   _4.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
      at <<Company>>.<<Product>>Web.ServiceAdapters.WebSockets.WebSocketManager.<Acceptor
   >d__4.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>
   d__6.MoveNext()
   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<EnsureDataAvaila
   bleOrReadAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<ReadNextFrameAsy
   nc>d__37.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<ReceiveAsync>d__
   36.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
      at <<Company>>.<<Product>>Web.ServiceAdapters.WebSockets.WebSocketBehaviour.<Run>d_
   _4.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
      at <<Company>>.<<Product>>Web.ServiceAdapters.WebSockets.WebSocketManager.<Acceptor
   >d__4.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>
   d__6.MoveNext()
   warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
         The response has already started, the error page middleware will not be ex
   ecuted.
   warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
         The response has already started, the error page middleware will not be ex
   ecuted.
   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
         Connection id "0HKVDQUJUEKU1": An unhandled exception was thrown by the ap
   plication.
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<EnsureDataAvaila
   bleOrReadAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<ReadNextFrameAsy
   nc>d__37.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<ReceiveAsync>d__
   36.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
      at <<Company>>.<<Product>>Web.ServiceAdapters.WebSockets.WebSocketBehaviour.<Run>d_
   _4.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
      at <<Company>>.<<Product>>Web.ServiceAdapters.WebSockets.WebSocketManager.<Acceptor
   >d__4.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>
   d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>
   d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<
   Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessi
   ngAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
         Connection id "0HKVDQUJUEKU0": An unhandled exception was thrown by the ap
   plication.
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<EnsureDataAvaila
   bleOrReadAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<ReadNextFrameAsy
   nc>d__37.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<ReceiveAsync>d__
   36.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
      at <<Company>>.<<Product>>Web.ServiceAdapters.WebSockets.WebSocketBehaviour.<Run>d_
   _4.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
      at <<Company>>.<<Product>>Web.ServiceAdapters.WebSockets.WebSocketManager.<Acceptor
   >d__4.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>
   d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>
   d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<
   Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
   ification(Task task)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessi
   ngAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
         Request finished in 2630.6342ms 101
   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
         Request finished in 11495.3447ms 101
   ```